# Why won't <audio> elements loop for files hosted on a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, audio

I'm testing with following HTML hosted on a node.js server:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Audio Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio src='/public/tests/audioTest.mp3' controls autoplay loop></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the audio will only play once when the page loads (Chrome only since it is mp3).

I suspect this is a node.js issue because the audio loops fine when I test this locally by just loading the HTML file without any webserver. It also works as expected on the Apache server that I tested it on. Additionally, if I link to an mp3 file hosted on an Apache server, it still works as expected with the HTML being served by the node server.

The audio also loops fine when encoded as [base64](http://jsfiddle.net/harbhub/nDkUQ/).

I am using version 0.8.14 of node.js. A live demo of the code hosted on node can be accessed [here](http://harbhub.com/public/tests/audioTest.html).

*EDIT*
The server has a directory named "public" which the server will always serve files from if they are requested.  The audio file and the html page are both in the "public" directory.

The node.js server code is as follows:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var mime = require('mime');//Third party library for looking up mime types
var handleRequest = function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/public/homePage.html').pipe(res);
    return;
  }
  else if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/public/favicon.ico').pipe(res);
    return;
  }
  else if (req.url.substr(0, 7) === '/public') {
    var mim = mime.lookup(req.url);
    var ext = mime.extension(mim);
    console.log('mime '+mim+' ext '+ext);
    if (ext !== 'bin') {
        fs.exists(__dirname+'/'+req.url, function(exists) {
            if (exists) {
                    if (req.headers.range) {
        var filename = __dirname+req.url;
        fs.readFile(filename, 'binary', function(err, file) {
          var header = {};
          var range = req.headers.range; 
          var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-"); 
          var partialstart = parts[0]; 
          var partialend = parts[1]; 

          var total = file.length; 

          var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10); 
          var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;

          header["Content-Range"] = "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + (total);
          header["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes";
          header["Content-Length"]= (end-start)+1;
          //header['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked';
          header["Connection"] = "close";

          res.writeHead(206, header); 
          res.write(file.slice(start, end)+'0', "binary");
          res.end();
          return;
        });
      }
      else {
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':mim});
        fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/'+req.url).pipe(res);
        return;
      }
            else {res.end();}
        });
    }
    else {res.end();}
  }
  else {res.end();}
};
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(8888);//Listening on port 8888
```

Comment: When you are saying you are hosting a file on a "Node.js server", that doesn't mean much, since you can write anything you want with Node.js.  Make sure you are specific in mentioning that you are using the built-in HTTP classes if you are, and provide the actual code you are using in Node.js, since that's where you think the problem is.

Comment: It looks like it would be possible to retrieve any file off your disk by doing a classic `../../../../../etc/passwd` or something.

Comment: @Brad I don't want my files to be that easy to retrieve!  I know this is a separate question, but what can I do to prevent such an easy retrieval method?

Comment: For what you are doing, I'd actually recommend adopting Express.  http://expressjs.com/guide.html  It is well suited for what you are doing, and if you use its `static` module, these sorts of protections are already in place.  It even handles `etag` stuff for caching, and might do range requests, but I am not certain.  If you don't want to use Express, just add a check to make sure that any file you load from disk is actually under the directory set as the document root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is because your Node.js server isn't responding to the range request.

Chrome is sending a range request for a certain set of bytes in the file.  I don't know why it would be incapable of looping without getting those bytes in the response, but that should be the only difference.

Comment: The audio file is in fact sending the range header.  What is the appropriate way to handle this: req.headers.range returns "bytes=0-" when the audio file is requested.

Comment: @MichaelHarbach, You should serve a `206` response code with the bytes requested.  Bytes `0-` means all bytes from the beginning of the file.  This is effectively a test to see of the server is capable of supporting range requests.  Chrome will then often immediately fire off a second request with a different range.  In my tests on your link, I see a request for `Range: bytes=0-29130` from Chrome, and your server only responds with `200` for the status code, as if it were a normal HTTP request.

Comment: When I send another request it returns:  bytes=0-29130

Comment: Okay, let me try to work it out.  I will set the an additional header for the Content-Range.

Comment: Can you perhaps give me a code snippet of how my server should be formatting the response?  I'm trying:  res.writeHead(206, {'Content-Range':res.headers.range}) but this is not working.

Comment: I've got it working!  I will update the question to include the solution.  Thanks for your guidance @Brad!

Comment: @MichaelHarbach, No problem!  Did the problem end up being the range headers?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  I would give you an Up Arrow Vote, but my reputation is below 15.  I have edited the question to include the solution for chrome and nodejs.

Comment: Credit to this for the appropriate way to format the header:  http://www.extrawurst.org/blog11/2012/06/streaming-media-in-nodejs/

Comment: Just a note... in that article you link to, the guy recommends setting your transfer encoding to chunked.  I don't recommend doing this.  It isn't necessary if you know the file size, and many streaming media clients do not properly implement chunked encoding.

Comment: Duly noted. I tested in chrome without the chunked encoding and it works fine.  I have decided to comment out the chunked encoding header.  Thanks for the advice!